# Story with a man with broken glasses disappearing from a motel room

Tags: tv, story-identification

What's this film or TV programme from the 80's, possibly early 90's:

A man and a woman in a motel-looking room. Years before the woman's partner or husband had disappeared from the same room.

He had had broken spectacles. I think the two of them had had an argument. When he closed the door, he vanished.

Now the woman has returned with her new partner [or a friend?] to try and re-enact the whole thing to try and work out what happened. This new man now also has broken glasses.

He is about to close the door in exactly the same way as had happened so many years before when the woman suddenly looks horrified. She goes to stop him, as though something has just dawned on her but it is too late. This man also disappears.

I'm afraid I don't remember anything else except that I have a vague sense of it having a 70's feel to it.  We've already ruled out Tales of the Unexpected. Now we're a little stuck.

Comment: People seem to be having fairly good luck in that movie identification thread you were linked to. Might try there.

Comment: Some of this sounds like the Syfy mini-series *The Lost Room*, as when someone is in the room and the door is closed on them, they vanish.

Comment: @Keen That was my innitial thought, however The Lost Room was aired in 2006.  Also the glasses where fully intact in The Lost Room.  Off topic but that was one of the best Sci-Fi mini-series in recent memory.

Comment: @Monty129 The question simply says there's a 70's feel to it, and the room itself (in universe) is from the 60's, so it could match.

Comment: That still wouldn't explain the broken glasses as in the series they are fully intact.

Answer (score 8):

This sounds like "[The Lorelei](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0397082/)"; ignore the misleading poster on that imdb page - it's for the "[Screen Two](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0297626/)" series of films as a whole, not this particular episode.

As far as I remember, the first disappearance that the woman observed wasn't her partner; he was a stranger wearing glasses, who barged into her hotel room, exclaimed "Oh, my God!", retreated from the room, and had vanished without a trace when the woman left the room to see where he went. In another early scene, related to a later scene, she observes a light repeatedly being switched on  and off in a window.

Later, she meets a man who bears an uncanny resemblance to the first man, except that he does not wear glasses. She accuses him of being the first man, which he denies, showing her that he wears contact lenses, not glasses. They have an affair, and while making love out of doors, he loses a contact lens, and after failing to find it, pulls out a pair of glasses, thus renewing the woman's suspicions.

While playing scrabble, the man plays words that lead her to suspect that he has been stalking her; she becomes angry, locks herself in the bathroom, and repeatedly switches the light on and off.

They end up staying at the same hotel, and the woman asks him to re-enact the scene of the first man's disappearance, which he does, and disappears just like the first man.